# ListPlot with X- and Y-range (whiskers & fences) for each point

Tags: plotting, charts

I want to plot some `{x,y}` data as points. For each x and y coordinate of each point I got a range I want to plot as well. The range should look like whiskers/fences of a `BoxWhiskerChart` but both vertically and horizontal.

I tried some options of `BoxWhiskerChart`, but I'm not sure if that is the right kind of plot to begin with. Is it possible to plot X- and Y-whiskers? How can I hide or replace the box? [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51149/boxwhiskerchart-without-whiskers) is a solution to hide the whiskers which is basically the opposite of what I want.

To get a better idea how the plot should look like I added an ungly version I created in Excel. (I couldn't turn the fences for the horizontal whiskers.)

[image: Plot I want]

Example data used:

Points

```
point1={1,2}
point2={2,3}
```

Range

```
point1xrange={0.5,1.5}
point1yrange={1.5,2.5}
point2xrange={1,3}
point2yrange={2,4}
```

To specify: all points lie within their range, but not always exactly in the middle.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you see the `ErrorBarPlots` and `ErrorBarFunction`?

Comment: Not yet, I wasn't familiar with `Needs` and the possibility of loading packages. `ErrorListPlot` does the trick.
Since I'm not familiar with StackExchange either: should I answer my own question? Or edit the answer into the question?

Comment: Well, you may. Or you may leave it like it is, since I believe this is an off-topic, since the answer exists in the documentation. For this reason I propose to close this question. But important here is that you got a satisfactory solution.

Comment: @phoenix-bs Self-answers are encouraged! Do go ahead and enter a self-answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alexei Boulbitch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/788/alexei-boulbitch) suggested the `ErrorBar Plotting Package`. With that, I came up with the following solution.

A normal `ListPlot` for the data points:

```
dataPointsPlot = ListPlot[{dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD, dataE},
PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 20}];
```

The `ErrorListPlot` from the package:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
errorListPlot=ErrorListPlot[{rangeData}, PlotStyle->AbsolutePointSize[0]}];
```

Then I use `Show[]` to combine both plots and configure them as I want.

[image: final-plot]

```
dataA = {{0.0154, 0.0171}, {0.017, 0.0215}, {0.0271, 0.0337}};
dataB = {{0.0321, 0.0339}, {0.0337, 0.0368}, {0.0398, 0.0466}};
dataC = {{0.0884, 0.1001}, {0.0826, 0.0948}, {0.0859, 0.0739}};
dataD = {{0.0842, 0.0862}, {0.1235, 0.1262}, {0.1199, 
    0.1303}, {0.1352, 0.1294}};
dataE = {{0.1363, 0.1406}, {0.1438, 0.131}, {0.1501, 0.1474}};

rangeData = {
{{0.0154, 0.0171}, 
    ErrorBar[{-0.0015, 0.0031}, {-0.0019, 0.0025}]}, {{0.017, 0.0215},
     ErrorBar[{-0.0017, 0.0034}, {-0.0024, 0.0031}]}, {{0.0271, 
     0.0337}, 
    ErrorBar[{-0.0027, 0.0054}, {-0.0038, 0.0049}]}, {{0.0321, 
     0.0339}, 
    ErrorBar[{-0.0032, 0.0064}, {-0.0038, 0.0049}]}, {{0.0337, 
     0.0368}, 
    ErrorBar[{-0.0034, 0.0067}, {-0.0041, 0.0053}]}, {{0.0398, 
     0.0466}, 
    ErrorBar[{-0.004, 0.008}, {-0.0052, 0.0067}]}, {{0.0884, 0.1001}, 
    ErrorBar[{-0.0088, 0.0177}, {-0.0112, 0.0145}]}, {{0.0826, 
     0.0948}, 
    ErrorBar[{-0.0083, 0.0165}, {-0.0106, 0.0137}]}, {{0.0859, 
     0.0739}, 
    ErrorBar[{-0.00860000000000001, 0.0172}, {-0.00829999999999999, 
      0.0107}]}, {{0.0842, 0.0862}, 
    ErrorBar[{-0.00839999999999999, 0.0168}, {-0.0097, 
      0.0125}]}, {{0.1235, 0.1262}, 
    ErrorBar[{-0.0123, 0.0247}, {-0.0142, 0.0183}]}, {{0.1199, 
     0.1303}, 
    ErrorBar[{-0.012, 0.024}, {-0.0146, 0.0189}]}, {{0.1352, 0.1294}, 
    ErrorBar[{-0.0135, 0.027}, {-0.0145, 0.0187}]}, {{0.1363, 0.1406},
     ErrorBar[{-0.0136, 0.0273}, {-0.0158, 0.0204}]}, {{0.1438, 
     0.131}, ErrorBar[{-0.0144, 0.0288}, {-0.0147, 0.019}]}, {{0.1501,
      0.1474}, ErrorBar[{-0.015, 0.03}, {-0.0165, 0.0213}]}
   };
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to `ErrorListPlot` is `BubbleChart` with a custom `ChartElementFunction`:

```
ClearAll[errorBubble]
errorBubble[ps_: 15, th_: 5, ws_: 5] := Module[{xmean = Mean@#[[1]], ymean = Mean@#[[2]], 
     xerror = #3[[1, 1]], yerror = #3[[1, 2]], 
     color = Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"]}, 
  {Lighter @ color, AbsoluteThickness[th], 
   Line[{{xmean - xerror[[1]], ymean}, {xmean + xerror[[2]],  ymean}}], 
   Line[{{xmean, ymean - yerror[[1]]}, {xmean,  ymean + yerror[[2]]}}], 
   Line[{Offset[{0, -ws}, {xmean - xerror[[1]], ymean}], 
      Offset[{0, ws}, {xmean - xerror[[1]], ymean}]}],
   Line[{Offset[{0, -ws}, {xmean + xerror[[2]], ymean}], 
      Offset[{0, ws}, {xmean + xerror[[2]], ymean}]}] ,
   Line[{Offset[{-ws, 0}, {xmean, ymean - yerror[[1]]}],
      Offset[{ws, 0},  {xmean,  ymean - yerror[[1]]}]}],
   Line[{Offset[{-ws,0}, {xmean, ymean + yerror[[2]]}], 
      Offset[{ws, 0},  {xmean,  ymean + yerror[[2]]}]}],
   color, AbsolutePointSize[ps], Point[{xmean, ymean}]}] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[20, {10, 2}];
errors = RandomReal[{1, 3}, {10, 2, 2}];
bcdata = Append[#, 1] -> #2 & @@@ Transpose[{data, errors}];

BubbleChart[bcdata, ChartStyle -> 97, ChartElementFunction -> errorBubble[]]
```

[image]

```
BubbleChart[bcdata, ChartStyle -> 97, ChartElementFunction -> errorBubble[20, 3, 10]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In versions 12.0+, you can use `Around`  + `ListPlot` as follows:

```
ClearAll[toAround]
toAround = MapThread[MapThread[Around]@*List, {##}] &;

points = {point1, point2};
ranges = {{point1xrange, point1yrange}, {point2xrange, point2yrange}};

toAround[points, ranges]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[toAround[points, ranges], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Wrap each data set with `List` to have points styled individually:

```
ListPlot[List /@ toAround[points, ranges], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

You can use the option [`IntervalMarkersStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalMarkersStyle.html) (also new in version 12.0) to style the whiskers and fences:

```
ListPlot[List /@ toAround[points, ranges], 
  PlotRange -> All,
  BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[10],
  IntervalMarkersStyle ->
    <|"FenceStyle" ->Directive[Thick, Red], 
      "FenceWidth"->.2,
      "WhiskerStyle" -> Thick|>]
```

[image]